# Query_vars support in Rest API

Tags: wp-query, rest-api, query-variable

I am trying to make query_vars work in rest api. In my code bellow if I call `wp-json/wp/v2/cpt?city=test`, my debug output always returns an empty string.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Test
 * Author:      Gecka <contact@gecka.nc>
 * License:     GNU General Public License v3 or later
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */

function cpt_init() {
    $args = [
        'label'               => 'Custom post',
        'supports'            => [ 'title', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ],
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'hierachical'         => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
    ];
    register_post_type( 'cpt', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_init' );

function cpt_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'city';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'cpt_register_query_vars' );

function cpt_posts_where( $where, WP_Query $wp_query ) {
    if('cpt' !== $wp_query->get('post_type') ) {
        return $where;
    }

    // debug output
    var_export( $wp_query->get('city') );
    
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cpt_posts_where', null, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

correct me, if i'm wrong, but query vars are not processed in REST requests. but there is other ways to make this work. not really sure, if this will help with your problem but hopefully it is at least a push in the right direction

```
function so380236_rest_cpt_query($args, $request)
{
    $query_params = $request->get_query_params();

     if (!array_key_exists('city', $query_params)) {
        //$args is your WP_Query[$args] array
        //example:
        $args['posts_per_page'] = 12;
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter('rest_cpt_query', 'so380236_rest_cpt_query', 10, 2);
```

the `posts_per_page` is just a jibberish example for you to understand, you could create/manipulate meta and or tax queries etc...

and the filter name `rest_cpt_query` is just an example as well: in this case `cpt` is the slug of your post type. change it to `post`, `page` or `your_custom_post_type_slug` and the filter will run on the respected post type.

[link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/) to the filter in use.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing but using `$request['city']`

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you should upvote it and mark it as accepted. This helps users with similar questions find a solution.

Comment: @Laurent yeah, i just made it the super save way. so i check, if the value is actually there. otherwise php would throw errors ala array key does not exist, yada yada. safety first ;)